# How do add multiple variables from a list into excel

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ip

Is there a way where i could put all of the email output from the list, into an excel? this is the code that i use.

```
Email = [['amzn-noc-contact@amazon.com',
  'aws-routing-poc@amazon.com',
  'abuse@amazonaws.com',
  'aws-rpki-routing-poc@amazon.com'],
 ['abuse@liquidweb.com', 'ipadmin@liquidweb.com'],
 ['arin-contact@google.com', 'network-abuse@google.com'],
 ['ipadmin@automattic.com', 'abuse@automattic.com'],
 None,
 ['ipadmin@automattic.com', 'abuse@automattic.com'],
 ['google-cloud-compliance@google.com', 'arin-contact@google.com'],
 None,
 ['abuse@amazonaws.com',
  'aws-rpki-routing-poc@amazon.com',
  'amzn-noc-contact@amazon.com',
  'aws-routing-poc@amazon.com'],
 None]
```

As you can see from the previous one, these are a few examples email that i got from the ip generating with the help of a library called IPwhois. Inside the list each ip has emails for reporting. After getting the email, i tried to run it with this code so that it would be put inside the table.

```
emails = pd.DataFrame(email, columns=['Emails'])
final=pd.concat([emails], axis = 1)
final
```

This is the output that i get

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

How to make it possible for each bracket in the list to be put inside each cell for each bracket? i tried to do `emails = pd.DataFrame([email], columns=['Emails'])` by adding another [] inside the variable email since it has more than one variable for an email, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I have found the solution, based on Jason Baker's answer i only need to add another bracket to the email

```
emails = [x for sublist in filter(None, [email]) for x in sublist]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Emails": emails})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comp to flatten nested list, filter to remove Nones. Finally pass a dict to pandas.

```
emails = [x for sublist in filter(None, Emails) for x in sublist]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Emails": emails})
```

Comment: I have edited my question @JasonBaker, is there a way to make it in the same cell? or maybe just output just one of the mail into the cell?

Comment: If you want a list in 1 cell. df = pd.DataFrame({"Emails": [emails]}) or if you want a comma delimited str use emails = ", ".join([x for sublist in filter(None, Emails) for x in sublist])
df = pd.DataFrame({"Emails": [emails]})